# Running sbt in docker as non-root user

Tags: docker, sbt

Trying to create a docker image that has sbt installed and can build sbt projects but, when building, will not be running as the root user (this is all in the context of running Jenkins inside docker).

Dockerfile sets up sbt

```
ENV SBT_VERSION=1.1.6
RUN \
  curl -L -o sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
  dpkg -i sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
  rm sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install sbt && \
  sbt sbtVersion
```

And if I then run sbt as the root user, all works ok

```
docker exec -u root myjenkins sbt sbtVersion
```

produces

```
[warn] No sbt.version set in project/build.properties, base directory: /
[info] Set current project to root (in build file:/)
[info] 1.1.6
```

But when I run sbt as the jenkins user, it tries to download sbt 1.1.6 again and eventually fails when it tries to modify an apt system file.

```
docker exec -u jenkins myjenkins sbt sbtVersion
```

produces:

```
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 1.1.6  (this may take some time)...
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.1.6/sbt-1.1.6.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#sbt;1.1.6!sbt.jar (68ms)
   .
   .
   .
[warn] No sbt.version set in project/build.properties, base directory: /
[error] java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/cache/apt/archives/lock (Permission denied)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that all of the "RUN" commands in your Dockerfile are as a `root` user.

SBT downloading Scala: Check where it is downloading. SBT by default downloads dependencies on `~/.ivy2` (and/or `~/.m2`). If you change user, your home also changes, so it will look for dependencies in `/home/jenkins/.ivy2`, then on `.ivy2` (double-check on this), which do not have those dependencies downloaded already, so it tries to download them.

About the `var/cache/apt/archives/lock`, it is trying to install via SBT via apt with your jenkins user, when you need to be privileged user to use apt. Your app-user should not need to install anything (or anything that requires root access), but rather build an image with all required installs and then use it as a separate user. Also, if apt gives you headaches, you can just install via download into folder, something like:

```
RUN \
curl -fsL http://downloads.typesafe.com/scala/$SCALA_VERSION/scala-$SCALA_VERSION.tgz | tar xfz - -C /usr/local && \
ln -s /usr/local/scala-$SCALA_VERSION/bin/* /usr/local/bin/
```

PS: You may want to run your container always as jenkins user, in that case you can use `USER jenkins` after you finished installations and do any additional unprivileged operations there.